# Identifying conventional vs natural drugs

Tags: openfda, products

Is there a way to identify which drugs are Conventional (Allopathic) drugs vs which drugs are Natural (Homeo, Ayurvedic) drugs from open FDA drug label repository?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment:

If you google `site:dailymed.nlm.nih.gov allopathic` (no quotes), you get pages like https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/fda/fdaDrugXsl.cfm?setid=71c4c9fd-e359-7c68-e053-2a95a90a3f68&type=display which say things like:

- "Disclaimer: This homeopathic product has not been evaluated by the Food and Drug Administration for safety or efficacy. FDA is not aware of scientific evidence to support homeopathy as effective."
- "unapproved homeopathic" under "Marketing category"
- "Product efficacy and claims are based on theories of homeopathy that are not supported by scientific evidence and most modern allopathic medical professionals"

Not sure how consistent these disclaimers are, but Marketing category seems like a possible start.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the openFDA Drug Label repository does not have a way to precisely identify conventional/natural drugs.